# 20thingsilearned two sided page flip with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to develop a page flip like http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US. I have found the case study on html5rocks http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/.

Many people already have asked on this site, how to use the left page. Unfortunately it seems, no one has a convenient answer.

So my question is: in what way must the code be adjusted so that the left page can be used?

Many thanks in advance.

Amy

Comment: The issue with depending on 3rd party plug-ins and code is that once you want step outside of what it already does, there isn't much support. I doubt you'll find anyone here willing to reverse-engineer the code to answer this question.

Comment: Dear Diodeus, thank you for your answer. The source code can be downloaded here http://www.html5rocks.com/static/demos/20things_pageflip/20Things_PageFlip_Example.zip, if this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

Why develop when there are a lot of these plugins available. The first I encountered while I was about to do the same thing was [TurnJS](http://www.turnjs.com/#home) which has left page turn as well. You can check out it's source.

Comment: Dear Joseph, thank you for your answer. I've already seen TurnJS. But I think that the 20thingsilearned-thing is more beautiful (especially the shadows are very well).
But I'm going to give it a second try.

Comment: The problem with TurnJS is:
 - license
 - Pages are rendered as images, I can copy/paste text